# GSON not deleted

Tags: android

Why in my APK there is GSON even though I have nothing to implement GSON in Gradle?

[Result Analyze APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPInT.jpg)

My Gradle :

```
//main
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.5"
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.1"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
implementation "com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1"

//google
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0"
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.0"

// third party dependencies
implementation "com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2"
implementation "com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0"
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.2"
implementation "com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:4.1.2"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation "com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0"

//kapt
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"

// test
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.2.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0"
```

I want to reduce my apk size, so I deleted the libary that I didn't use.

Answer (score 0):

One or more of your dependencies has `GSON` in self.
i think it might be `Glide` or someone else.

for redecuing apk size check this topic might be helpful: [Reduce the APK size - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size)